# How to "gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries" via Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, bundler, gemfile

There is a known error installing the latest version of Nokogiri. The workaround is to manually install using

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

But how can this be done via the Gemfile?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Run

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
```

After running this command, every time Bundler needs to install the nokogiri gem, it will pass along the flags you specified.

It remembers this setting by adding an entry to your `~/.bundle/config` file:

```
---
BUNDLE_BUILD__NOKOGIRI: "--use-system-libraries"
```

Comment: cool. are there any differences or considerations between using this approach on local dev environment (mac os) and on production dev environment (linux)?

Comment: FYI I added the config file to my application directory, per the [docs](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html)

Comment: FYI I needed to REMOVE this setting in order to make nokogiri 1.8.4 (used by `slather`) work again on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 5):

#### System-wide way:

```sh
bundle config --global build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
```

Saves configuration to `$HOME/.bundle/config` (this path is configurable), so that it is shared by all projects.

The `--global` parameter is default, hence one may omit it.

#### Application-wide way

```sh
bundle config --local build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
```

Saves configuration to `<project_root>/.bundle/config`, so that it is confined to gemfiles contained in this directory.

#### Reverting

```sh
bundle config --delete build.nokogiri
```

Removes `build.nokogiri` setting from both global and local configuration files.

#### See also

Bundler docs: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html